# How to figure out if docker master or agent running

Tags: docker

How to figure out if docker master or agent running?

I do `sudo docker version` and this is what I get:

```
$ sudo docker version
Client version: 1.5.0
Client API version: 1.17
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): a8a31ef/1.5.0
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.5.0
Server API version: 1.17
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): a8a31ef/1.5.0
```

Is this a docker agent or a docker master? Is the master the daemon or the agent... or both?

Comment: you guys are correct: there is no master-agent architecture. There is docker daemon and its containers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output explicitly says:

```
Client version: 1.5.0
```

That is the version of your docker client - that command line tool - which you were using to get those information.

```
Server version: 1.5.0
```

That is the version of your docker server (or host, or daemon).

But what do you mean with *agents*? I do not know that term in the Docker context.

On a server you could start *containers* with `docker run` commands issued by the client. For a container you can get information about which image and tag is used by typing `docker inspect --format='{{.Config.Image}}' <containerName>`.

Answer (score 1):

I just use docker ps and see if it works, I think this is the client, docker should be executed via systemctl